# How is this solution below logically accurate?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, problem-solving

I was attempting a question on vector algebra.

If $a,b,c$ are unit vectors satisfying :

$|a-b|^2 +|b-c|^2 +|c-a|^2 =9$, find the value of $|2a + 5b + 5c|.$

This was the solution:

[image]

($a\cdot b+b\cdot c+c\cdot a=-3/2,$ they directly assumed all $3$ angles to be $120$ degrees)

This assumption baffled me. Yet it gave them the correct answer.

When are such assumptions valid, or, when can such an assumption give us a correct answer and when will it fail?

Comment: Show that for unit vectors, $ \sum \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} \geq -3/2$, with equality attained when they are co-planar and spaced $120^\circ$ apart. Alternatively, show that $|a+b+c| = 0 $, so we get an equilateral triangle, and thus the angle between them is $120^\circ$ $\quad$ So, a generous interpretation is that they merely didn't explain why that conclusion is true.